# Can a Samsung NX300 shoot without a lens, for attaching to a telescope?

Tags: astrophotography, samsung

Can I take pictures on my NX300 without a lens attached?

I have read threads about this, however my issue is somewhat different. I want to attach my camera to my telescope, and take astro-pictures. I have all the required hardware, I have an adapter for my camera to a T2 mount, which then connects to my telescope.

The issue is that my camera will not react, and only tell me "no lens". As its not a professional camera (only a NX300) the switch to manual focus is on the lens itself.

If there is no way to do it officially, are there any software hacks which will allow it?

Answer (score 4):

In order for the camera to fire, a small spring loaded connection has to be pushed in far enough.

If you take off the lens and look in the exact opposite direction of the red dot, you will see a small metal point sticking out. That is it.

The challenge is to ensure that the T2 mount you purchase is designed specifically for the Samsung NX range of cameras. Without the correct adaptor, the connection will not be pushed in far enough and result in "no lens" error.

The correct mount will press this connection and you should then be able to use it with any T2 mount lens or telescope. However, this only works in the cameras Manual or Aperture modes.

You can also use some sticky tape to correct this, but that is at your own risk and can cause issues if not done correctly.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

In many cameras, to get this to work, you enable "release without lens" in the camera menu. However, this doesn't seem to be available in the case of the Samsung NX300.

According this [this thread](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3502012) on DPReview, "Your adapter just has to depress the mechanical switch in the lens mount. Some adapters are problematic, most are fine." If the adapter you have is not depressing the mechanical switch enough, you might be able to fudge it by following the suggestion in the following video:

[Overcome Samsung NX Lens Adapter "No Lens Error"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhVgxSgF6Ow)